# populate database using irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.2.3

My need is populating a database using an easiest way.
So I created a model

```
rails g model MyModelName title:string, another_title:string, description:text
```

Now I'm trying to populate a database some data using irb

```
mm = MyModelName.create :title =>'title1', :another_title=>'fdfds', :description =>'desc1 fdsfds'
```

But here is an error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MyModelName
    from (irb):4
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Migrate your database and inside rails console execute command `reload!`

Comment: What is rails console? I'm using `irb`.

Comment: instead of `irb`, go to the root of your app and run `rails c`

Comment: Alex, consider reading some new book on Rails or at least guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run `rake db:migrate` yet?

Are you using `rails console`?